# Compile error when compiling a driver using Makefile

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

When I try to compile the hello.c as a driver component, I got an error as follows:

```sh
root@ubuntu:/home/steven/Downloads# make
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=/home/steven/Downloads modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/steven/Downloads/hello.o
**cc1: error: code model kernel does not support PIC mode**
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/home/steven/Downloads/hello.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/steven/Downloads/hello.o] Error 1
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/home/steven/Downloads' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/steven/Downloads] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic'
Makefile:13: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

My Makefile is as follows:

```make
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
MODULE_NAME = hellomodule
$(MODULE_NAME)-objs := hello.o
obj-m := $(MODULE_NAME).o
else
KERNEL_DIR = /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build
MODULEDIR := $(shell pwd)

.PHONY: modules
default: modules

modules:
    make -C $(KERNEL_DIR) M=$(MODULEDIR) modules

clean distclean:
    rm -f *.o *.mod.c .*.*.cmd *.ko
    rm -rf .tmp_versions
endif
```

Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I am using ubuntu18.04 and GCC version is 7.3.0

Comment: Can you check this question, does it relate to your question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/851433/kernel-doesnt-support-pic-mode-for-compiling ?

Comment: It seems that does not work for me :( @danglingpointer

Answer (score 0):

I realize my response might be too lated. However, personally, I find the linked answer insufficient when it comes to handling existing kernel compatibility.

For example, you might possess a kernel module without access to the kernel's source code. In such situations, my suggestion is to utilize a container solution like Docker.

You can accomplish this by executing the following command:

➜  build sudo docker run -d --name ubuntu_14 -p 8000:22 -it --privileged -v /home:/home -v /boot:/boot -v /lib/modules:
/lib/modules -v /usr/src/:/usr/src ubuntu:14.04

Within the Docker container, you can conveniently build your modules, eliminating any potential compatibility issues with the older kernel.

- Note that your answer is related to GCC compatibility.
- This answer can be utilized for any other compatibility issues with building the old kernel.

Comment: Kernel source code is not needed in most of the cases for the simplest modules.